# Objects of array Group by object key

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, arraylist

I have done a number of iterations but haven't achieved by expectation.
I have array of Object like one pair below

```
 const data = [
       {
            "credit_account_id": "244",
            "debit_account_id": null,
            "sum": "30.00",
            "name": "Bank"
        },
        {
            "credit_account_id": null,
            "debit_account_id": "244",
            "sum": "110.00",
            "name": "Bank"
        },

         ....
    ]
```

i want to achieve

```
[
    {   name: "Bank",
        account : "244",
        debit_account : "30",
        credit_account: 110
    }
]
```

Comment: What's the rule that generates the "expected output"? Why is it `110`, and not `140`? Why do you group `debit_account_id`s with `credit_account_id`s?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? You will find plenty of similar questions and answers here on SO.

Comment: Please, provide more details. Which field should be taken from which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const data = [
       {
            "credit_account_id": "244",
            "debit_account_id": null,
            "sum": "30.00",
            "name": "Bank"
        },
        {
            "credit_account_id": null,
            "debit_account_id": "244",
            "sum": "110.00",
            "name": "Bank"
        }

    ]

    
    const dd = [];
            data.map((d) => {
              const item = dd.find((x) => x.name === d.name);
              if (item) {
                if (d.debit_account_id) {
                  item.debit_account = d.sum;
                }
                return (item.credit_account = d.sum);
              }
              const obj = { name: d.name };
              if (d.debit_account_id) {
                obj.debit_account = d.sum;
                obj.ledger_account = d.debit_account_id;
              } else {
                obj.credit_account = d.sum;
                obj.ledger_account = d.credit_account_id;
              }
              return dd.push(obj);
            });
```

console.log(dd)

```
 [
        {   name: "Bank",
            account : "244",
            debit_account : "30",
            credit_account: 110
        }
    ]
```

Comment: If you don't use the return value of `.map()` then `.map()` is the wrong tool.